An exercise about infinite set in《The Foundations of Analysis：A Straightforward Introduction》(K. G. Binmore)
This is an exercise in “12.2 Cardinality” of 《The Foundations of Analysis：A Straightforward Introduction》(K. G. Binmore) .The exercise is as follows：

Suppose that $f:\{1,2,\ldots,m \}\to S$ and $g:\{1,2,\ldots,n \}\to T$ are bijections. If $S \cap T=\varnothing$, construct a bijection $h:\{1,2,\ldots,m+n\}\to S \cup T$. Deduce that the union of two finite sets $A$ and $B$ is finite. [Hint: $A \cup B=A \cup (B \setminus A)$.] Hence prove that,if $C$ is infinite and $D$ is finite,then $C \setminus D$ is infinite. Deduce that any subset of a finite set is finite.[Hint: suppose that $C \subset D$.]

My question is: how to prove “if $C$ is infinite and $D$ is finite,then $C \setminus D$ is infinite” in this exercise? In this book, there is no conclusion that the intersection of two finite sets is a finite set. There is also no method for determining finite and infinite sets. It only provides a definition of finite sets：a set $S$ contains $n$ elements if there exists a bijection $f: {1, 2, 3, \ldots , n} \to S$. If, for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, a set $S$ has $n$ elements (or $S= \varnothing$), we say that $S$ is a finite set. Otherwise $S$ is an infinite set.
Please follow the hints in this exercise when proving, thank you. I really don't have any ideas.

Does the posted question have a typo: in the 2nd paragraph, should it be : If $~S ~\color{red}{\cap} ~T = \emptyset,~$...?

You state "In this book, there is no conclusion that the intersection of two finite sets is finite", but nothing you are asking about involves the intersection of sets. (And the conclusion you are asked to deduce implies that the intersection is finite.) And you  state "There is also no method for determining finite and infinite sets.", but follow by giving the definitions of "finite" and "infinite" provided by the book. Definitions are methods of determining the things they define.

Since you don't ask about the first part of the question, I assume you managed to show that if $A,B$ are finite, then so is $A\cup B$? Now suppose $C\setminus D$ is finite, and apply that result to $D$ and $C\setminus D$. What conclusion do you reach about $C$?

Thanks, I've corrected it,  S ∩ T=∅.

Thank you for your answer.But D∪(C∖D)=D∪C,apply that result I only come to the conclusion “D∪C is finite”.
Other books use “a set is infinite if and only if it is equipotent to a proper subset” to determine if a set is infinite.This exercise mentioned the conclusion about the union of finite sets . Other than that, there is no conclusion about the intersection or difference of finite sets in this book.
I mention these pieces of information in order to find an answer in line with the author's ideas.
